# How to enable scanning and scan period like logback functionality in Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, logback

Provided below is my spring boot application deployment structure.
I am using the configuration externalization to overwrite spring boot properties.
 I am using the default logging configuration provided by spring-boot. 
In logback.xml, I would set scan="true" scanPeriod="30 sec" and any log level changes would be reflected, at run time without restarting the server. 
How would I accomplish the same here?

```
/var/lib/micro-service/micro-service.jar 
/var/lib/micro-service/application.properties
/var/lib/micro-service/micro-service.conf
```

Thanks in advance.